# Solving with an inverse matrix but no b

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, problem-solving

So here's what I'm looking at: I'm given two matrices, A and A^-1

$$
A = \pmatrix{I&0&0\\ A&I&0\\B&D&I}, \quad 
A^{-1} = \pmatrix{I & 0 & 0\\ P & I & 0\\ Q & R & I}.
$$

I'm asked to solve for P, Q, and R. I'd expect to use **x** = A^-1**b**, but I am not given b.

I noticed that both matrices have the same upper-right form - I on the main diagonal and all zeros above. Is that significant?

Thank you.

Comment: Are these block matrices, or is $I$ supposed to be $1$ and the other unknowns scalars? Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your mathematical expressions.

Comment: I believe these are block matrices. I'll be sure to use MathJax, I didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Using [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication), compute the product $AA^{-1}$ in terms of $A,B,D,P,Q,R$. Using the fact that $AA^{-1}$ must be the identity matrix, we end up with a system of three equations that we can solve to write $P,Q,R$ in terms of $A,B,D$.

To answer your explicit question: yes, the structure of the matrix is significant since with a different structure, the resulting system might not have a solution. However, this fact does not need to be explicitly considered in solving the problem.

Comment: Well, that makes a lot of sense. Makes me feel a bit silly, as that is one of the properties that I was taught about inverse matrices. Thank you!